# how many threads can be created in R?

Tags: multithreading, r, dll

I have built a DLL in which 50 threads are created in function HelloWorld.

Then I try to call HelloWorld in R. `(dyn.load("...dll");  .C("HelloWorld");`
In `R 2.11.1`, it is OK. But in `R i386 2.15.2`, it fails with Short of Memory error. 
It fails at the 23th thread.

Is is a bug in `R2.15`?

Comment: In fact，R 2.12.2，R2.14.2 and R i386 2.15.1 are all OK.

Comment: It is better to edit your original post to add this info.